# MS SQL Server query returns only if selected columns have different values

Tags: sql-server

How do I create an SQL query that will return records of same IP addresses only if two or more records Version different, i.e. query should return

```
IP_Address      Version
10.10.10.10      11                         
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      12
```

but not

```
IP_Address      Version
10.10.10.10      11                         
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11   
10.10.10.10      11
```

What do I add in

```
select * from dbo.Computers
where IP_Address = '10.10.10.10'
```

There is no telling what the Version will be, it can be any number

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for filtered grouping results.

```
SELECT IP_Address
, Version
FROM dbo.Computers
WHERE IP_Address in (SELECT IP_Address
FROM dbo.Computers
GROUP BY IP_Address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Version) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT IP_Address,COUNT([Version]) OVER(PARTITION BY IP_Address,Version) AS [CountVersion],COUNT(IP_Address) OVER(PARTITION BY IP_Address) AS [CountIP]
             FROM dbo.Computers)
SELECT A.IP_Address, A.Version
FROM dbo.Computers A    
WHERE A.IP_Address IN(SELECT DISTINCT IP_Address FROM CTE WHERE CountIP>CountVersion)
ORDER BY IP_Address, Version
```

This query uses a common table expression to do the counts and the display the IP addresses that have more than one version listed.